# Volume of Parallelepiped and Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

I understand that the absolute value of the determinant of a 3x3 matrix is the volume of the parallelepiped. I also understand that the determinant of a 3x3 rotation matrix is 1, as rotations preserve both volume and orientation. Now say I have a rotation matrix with a determinant that is not equal to 1, but equal to some positive integer (instead of a 1 in the rotation matrix there is some other number in its place). Would this matrix be rotating, as well as scaling by the factor of the determinant? Let's say the value of the determinant is 5, would this be scaling by a factor of 5 since the volume of the parallelepiped is now 5? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? If anyone can explain or point me to some readings/videos I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the determinant captures. This video has a great visualization of the determinant. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk&vl=en

Comment: The determinant of a 2x2 matrix captures information about areas, while the determinant of a 3x3 captures information about volumes.

Comment: @ndhanson3 Excellent choice of video :D

Comment: @ndhanson3 that video was really helpful. Thank you!